# Can we develop plugins for shopify using MERN stack?

Tags: shopify, mern

I checked on various blogging site or on google but I did not get the answer of this question. So can anyone tell me if we can create plugin or POS type application for shopify websites using MERN stack?

If yes, can you please share links which will help me to look more into the same topic? It would be great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create any kind of app you want with your stack. There is nothing special about that stack that would prevent you from developing a web application with it. It is after all suitable since you get a database, web server, and the scripting to tie it all into an API-driven platform.

I have built hundreds of Shopify Apps, and some have used MongoDB, some have used Express, and some have used React, so clearly, to me at least, if I have done it in production, you can too!